# commands "cf login" , "cf api" raising exception

Tags: sdk, sap-cloud-foundry

When I run the command

```
cf api https://api.cf.us10.hana.ondemand.com
```

or

```
cf login
```

The following exception is raised.

> Exception 0xc0000005 0x0 0x42024dbf 0x7ffdcf080e57
> PC=0x7ffdcf080e57

Though, I reinstalled the CF CLI this exception is still occurring. Can someone please help me?

Thanks in Advance.

-Sankeerth

Comment: your command is working fine for me, status is OK. can you please check your proxies.

Comment: you can also try with cf login -a https://your_api_name